# I want to create a box that has minimum heigh but expands with the content upto a max height

Tags: flutter

I want to create a box that has minimum heigh but expands with the content upto a max height.

The below code always ends up taking the max height. That might be because the children of `ConstrainedBox` have infinite height. But I'm struggling on how can I contain their height if the text isn't that long.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.white70,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 150.0, maxHeight: 200.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 7,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      task.title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        TaskStateWidget.of(context).deleteTask(id: task.id);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.highlight_off)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => onTap(),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      task.description,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: true,
                      maxLines: 8,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: add ```mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min``` in ```Column```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something very small.